# How to replace a classic for loop with df.iterrows()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a huge data frame.

I am using a for loop in the below sample code:

```
for i in range(1, len(df_A2C), 1):
    A2C_TT= df_A2C.loc[(df_A2C['TO_ID'] == i)].sort_values('DURATION_H').head(1)
    if A2C_TT.size > 0:
        print (A2C_TT)
```

This is working fine but I want to use df.iterrows() since it will help me to automaticall avoid empty frame issues.

I want to iterate through `TO_ID` and looking for `minimum values` accordingly.

**How should I replace my classical `i` loop counter with df.iterrows()?**

**Sample Data:**

```
FROM_ID TO_ID   DURATION_H  DIST_KM
1   7   0.528555556 38.4398
2   26  0.512511111 37.38515
3   71  0.432452778 32.57571
4   83  0.599486111 39.26188
5   98  0.590516667 35.53107
6   108 1.077794444 76.79874
7   139 0.838972222 58.86963
8   146 1.185088889 76.39174
9   158 0.625872222 45.6373
10  208 0.500122222 31.85239
11  209 0.530916667 29.50249
12  221 0.945444444 62.69099
13  224 1.080883333 66.06291
14  240 0.734269444 48.1778
15  272 0.822875    57.5008
16  349 1.171163889 76.43536
17  350 1.080097222 71.16137
18  412 0.503583333 38.19685
19  416 1.144961111 74.35502
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add the first n rows of your `df_A2C`? Makes it easier to give a good answer. Usually it's bad to use loops when working with dataframes

Comment: @bitflip I have added up some samples of the data at the end of question. Please have a look

Comment: @bitflip I agree with you. I am facing lots of invisible challenges.

Comment: Whats the first column? An Index? Please do:
`df_A2C.head(10).to_dict()`

Comment: this does the same as your example as far as I can test: `df.groupby('TO_ID').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('DURATION_H').head(1))`
but I have no idea what you are trying to do here, no I hope it is useful

Comment: @bitflip Sorry, It was a mistake. I have updated the data again. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way about it

```
# run the loop for as many unique TO_ID you have
# instead of iterrows, which runs for all the DF or running to the size of DF

for idx  in np.unique(df['TO_ID']):
    A2C_TT= df.loc[(df['TO_ID'] == idx)].sort_values('DURATION_H').head(1)
        print (A2C_TT)
```

```
        ROM_ID  TO_ID  DURATION_H   DIST_KM
498660      39      7    0.434833  25.53808
```

here is another way about it

```
df.loc[df['DURATION_H'].eq(df.groupby('TO_ID')['DURATION_H'].transform(min))]
```

```
ROM_ID  TO_ID   DURATION_H  DIST_KM
498660  39  7   0.434833    25.53808
```

Comment: I think we do not need this if statement anymore, right?

Comment: yes. removed it and added an alternate solution

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question, you want to group your data by To_ID and select the row where Duration_H is the smallest? Is that right?

```
df.loc[df.groupby('TO_ID').DURATION_H.idxmin()]
```

Comment: Yes. Perfect. This is what I wanted. Is it possible to remove the index number while doing `df.loc[df.groupby('TO_ID').DURATION_H.idxmin()]`?

Comment: Is FROM_ID your index? You can either use .drop() to remove the column or .reset_index() to reset your index

Comment: Actually from_ID is an inform but since I am using data from an excel file it has an index value. I used reset_index().

Comment: I have used reset_index() but now there are two index numbers. One with no column name, other with name index. Both are starting with 0. Why there is a duplication?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is to set FROM_ID as index like this:
`.set_index("FROM_ID")`  `df.loc[df.groupby('TO_ID').DURATION_H.idxmin()].set_index("FROM_ID")`

Comment: Actually, I need only `FROM_ID TO_ID DURATION_H DIST_KM`. From_ID is representing an ambulance. It is not an index number.